# Can't read Serial Input

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino

I have an Arduino hooked up via usb to my computer.  From it I try to read the from the COM port.

Can anyone see if theres anything blatantly wrong with this???

```
void main()
{   
    int exitStatus;
    unsigned int bytesToRead = 1;
    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) + 1);
    Serial *connection = new Serial("COM3");

    if(connection->IsConnected()){
        exitStatus=connection->ReadData(buffer, bytesToRead);
        if( *buffer > 0)
            <statement I'm trying to hit>
    }

}
```

Right now it always hits the 'statement I'm trying to hit' even when it's no supposed to.  Debugging it always shows that the contents of buffer is a lot of junk.  I know what's coming in from the serial input should be right because from what I'm seeing in the serial monitor, it all looks good.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not evaluating the `exitStatus` variable, which might indicate it the read was successful.

Also you don't need to malloc memory if you want to read just one byte, you can simply pass the pointer to a local char variable.

And while I'm at it, the type for main is either `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char** argv)`

```
int main()
{   
    int exitStatus;
    unsigned int bytesToRead = 1;
    unsigned char buffer;
    Serial *connection = new Serial("COM3");

    if(connection->IsConnected()){
        exitStatus=connection->ReadData(&buffer, 1);
        if((exitStatus == <Insert the value for a correct read status>) && (buffer != '0'))
            <statement I'm trying to hit>
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**update**
Changed the != 0 check to != '0', since I suspect that there is a '0' character (=0x30) comming from the serial interface.

Comment: ah, my bad on that.  I've worked this code over so many times I didn't notice that.  But that's not the problem.  It always reports a successful read by setting exitStatus as the number of bytes that were read.

Comment: @ZacAttack Can you check with a terminal program if there is really no communication? Also is the port correct configured (baudrate, stopbits, parity). I see no obvious problem in you code.

Comment: I'm using The Arduino serial monitor to look at whats coming in.  It's a stream of '0's unless I press a button down.  Then while it's down it's a stream on '1's.  I've added your fixes, and they definitely cleaned the place up!  But I'm still getting odd results in the debugger

Comment: and the baudrate is fine, I'm looking at the parity and stopbits now

Comment: I actually don't know how to determine what combination of parity and stopbits I should be using.

Comment: Should I post a new question?

Comment: @ZacAttack It might be the difference between '0' (the ASCII-Char Zero) and 0

Comment: @ZacAttack I changed the code to chech againts '0' characters.